# How to stop extending cookie expiration time for ajax calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity, owin

I set ExpireTimeSpan to one day ,but i have notification service in the UI that send ajax call each 5 minutes ,so the ajax call will extend the expiration time ,as result of that the system will not logout after period of time if the user is in active ,how could i resolve that

```
        int expireTime = 1440; //one day

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
         {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(expireTime),
            SlidingExpiration=true, 
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

i found this solution for asp.net core :
https://medium.com/cacti-pins/conditionally-set-sliding-expiration-time-on-authentication-cookies-in-asp-net-core-e70ffe7da49d
but i'm using .net4.5

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a particularly simple solution to this issue, but there are a couple of avenues you could look at.

First of all you could consider using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) for the notification service. In a C# application it would seem sensible to use [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr). This will allow you to open a persistent connection between client and server and enable a server push, which should only involve sending the cookie on the initial connection. Beware that by default SignalR can downgrade to long polling if other options are not supported within the browser which would still suffer from the same issue.

Alternatively you could look at swapping the ajax call for a javascript `fetch()`. This will allow you to omit the cookie when you make a request. You will however need to generate an alternative Authorization token within your application and manage this. You may also need to move the notification service into its own application so that it is not using the same authentication scheme.

Comment: i used this filter before the action but i don't know how to clear owin cookie in the response     
       public class DoNotExtendAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
       {
   // how to clear owin cookie in the response

        }

Comment: I'm not sure that will help - authentication happens further up the pipeline, all you will do is log the user out on the next full request